# Merge/Join 2 dictionaries based on a column in Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, join, merge, append

I have read 2 csv files into 2 separate dictionaries. Now I need to merge or join them based on a zipcode column, Please advise. Here is the sample data:

Data1:

```
{
  '10029': {'Zipcode': '10029', 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY'},
  '11221': {'Zipcode': '11221', 'City': 'Brooklyn', 'State': 'NY'},
  '10162': {'Zipcode': '10162', 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY'}
}
```

Data2:

```
{
  '10029': {'Zipcode': '10029', 'Latitude': '40.82374', 'Longitude': '-73.9373'},
  '11211': {'Zipcode': '11211', 'Latitude': '40.72354', 'Longitude': '-73.98295'},
  '10162': {'Zipcode': '10162', 'Latitude': '41.75554', 'Longitude': '-72.94225'}
}
```

Merged_Date (expected result):

```
{
  '10029': {'Zipcode': '10029', 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY', 'Latitude': '40.82374', 'Longitude': '-73.9373'},
  '10162': {'Zipcode': '10162', 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY''Latitude': '41.75554', 'Longitude': '-72.94225'}
}
```

Since there are only 2 matches.

Code I have, which seems to be not working:

```
Data1[Zipcode] = Data2
    if Data1[Zipcode] == Data2['Zipcode']:
        Data1= Data2.append(['Zipcode'],['Longitude'],['Latitude'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `append` to a dictionary.

What I would do is:

```
merged = dict()
for key in Data1:
  if key in Data2:
    merged[key] = {**Data1[key], **Data2[key]}

print(merged)
```

Result:

```
{
  '10029': {'Zipcode': '10029', 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY', 'Latitude': '40.82374', 'Longitude': '-73.9373'}, 
  '10162': {'Zipcode': '10162', 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY', 'Latitude': '41.75554', 'Longitude': '-72.94225'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the first data keys, check if this key is in the second dict and if so, merge both dicts:

```py
merged_data = dict()
for key in Data1.keys():
    if key in Data2.keys():
        merged_data.update({key: {**Data1[key], **Data2[key]}})
```

If you would rather use dict comprehension:

```py
merged_data = {k: {**Data1[k], **Data2[k]} for k in Data1.keys() if k in Data2.keys()}
```